# Enable web api attribute routing in global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'd like to enable Attribute Routing for Web API as it looks like it will make routing easier to define.  The example here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2 shows how it is done in the WebApiConfig.cs file:

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApplication
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            // Other Web API configuration not shown.
        }
    }
}
```

However, my project is an old web forms project, originally started in .Net 2.0 (it's now 4.5 following several upgrades over the years).  I don't have a WebApiConfig.cs file and instead my current routes are defined directly in the global.asax Application_Start method using:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(...)
```

Can anyone explain the best way to enable attribute based routing in this situation?
Thanks

Comment: read the link you posted under "Note: Migrating From Web API 1"

Comment: @rhumborl Thanks for the suggestion.  Interestingly though, I don't have the line it mentions `WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);` in global.asax

Comment: Wow, downvotes?  Was this a bad question?  Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can just do `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` in your `Global.asax` file.

`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration` object is passed to `WebApiConfig` file, so you can use this class to configure all you need in `Global.asax`

Answer (score 11):

You should put these 2 lines before your route definitions and it will work happily

```
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
```

Cheers